# Process.Start(url) sometimes one instance fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, process.start

I need some help!!!

ASPX.NET/C#- Call Process.Start(url) several times, sometimes one instance fails without error!!

I have a program that calls a http aspx.net with arguments(URL) to execute some stuff.
That program are invoking 10 times that aspx.net (all in the same time) with diferents urls.

But sometimes, one of the calls (url) do not launch in browser.

Code is very simple:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
                string URL = Request.Params["URL"];
                Logger.Log("CURRENT URL TO LAUNCH->", URL);

                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                    startInfo.Arguments = URL;
                    Process.Start(startInfo);

                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("Exception", ex);

        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You could (should) scrap the idea of launching internet explorer (from a service account under IIS) entirely and do whatever you need to do directly with an HttpWebRequest.

Comment: What do you mean?!? The HTTP requests are made from DataBase.

Comment: And the URL launch are a client side technology!And that´s because i need to open the IE in WebServer!

Comment: Why is there some javascript (?) client side stuff? Couldn't the web server do that stuff? Also: who is closing the IE instances?

Comment: Is not javascript! It´s silverlight web application to generate reports!The silverlight application closes the IE instances after finish. Everything goes right, except sometimes in 10 requests one fail

Comment: Any ideas to fixe this?Thanks!!